# How do i select this id attribute using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to fetch the value of id attribute i.e `1_4` from the `<img>` tag.

```
<a class="toggle" href="#toggle">
    <img src="tick.png" id="1_4" alt="No">
</a>
```

I am using the jQuery code.

```
$('.toggle').live('click', function() {

});
```

How do i select the value of id attribute within the jQuery code.

thank you.

Comment: note: to start and ID with a number is not w3c valid

Comment: is it? i need to assign and fetch some value, that is why i am using `id` which may be wrong for the purpose, do you think i should be using hidden field instead?

Comment: i think it would be better, to avoid missuse of attributes... (like alt="No" does sound wrong to me to ;) ) If you are using html5 you can use the data attribute

Comment: No is being used for displaying text incase the image is not loaded, it is the alternate text i want to display. is it not right to do so?

Comment: @meo It is valid to start an ID attribute value with a number in HTML5. See http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class

Comment: i did not know that it changed in html5 thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.toggle').live('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).find('img').attr('id');
});
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$('.toggle').live('click', function() {
  var id = $('img', this).prop('id');
});
```

Comment: ID is an attribute, not a property. (might be also available through one though)

Comment: @ThiefMaster Why would you use `.getAttribute('id')` if you can just do `.id`? Function calls are generally much slower than property lookups or array item lookups.

Comment: +1, for the only answer using `prop` instead of `attr`.  @ThiefMaster: property lookups are faster than attribute lookups - this goes doubly for jQuery since it does a lot with `attr` behind the scenes to work around old browser issues.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.toggle').live('click', function() {
  var id = $(this).find('img').attr('id');
});
```

Comment: i have multiple images with different dynamic id's, that code just shoes the last id.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.toggle').live('click', function() {
    alert( $(this).find('img:eq(0)').attr('id') );
});
```

Comment: No need for the `:eq(0)`, `.attr()` will automatically return the `id` of the first matched element.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need:

```
$('.toggle').find('img').attr('id');
```

See it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sikrip/FBEV7/)

Also, have a look in [jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) :)

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
$('.toggle').live('click', function() {
    alert($(this).children('img').attr('id'));
});
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/6KG6V/1